# For loop which returns a wrong array of elements

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I have a command button with a code like this:

```
Dim array1()
Dim nrow As Integer

nrow = Range("C4:C241").Count

ReDim array1(nrow)

For i = 0 To nrow
    'array1(i) = Range("C" & i + 3)
    array1(i) = i
Next

Range("AY4:AY" & nrow + 3) = array1
```

The comment symbols `'` is present in the case you wanted to switch to make some experiments.

What I get running this macro in Excel is a column of values equal to `0`, which is not what I would expect to get: I would like to print `array1` in the `Range("AY4:AY241")`.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `Tranpose` for your intended output.

```
Sub dural()
    Dim array1()
    Dim nrow As Integer
    nrow = Range("C4:C241").Count
    ReDim array1(nrow)
    For i = 0 To nrow
        array1(i) = i
    Next
    Range("AY4:AY" & nrow + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(array1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I did not think it returned by default a row array :)

Comment: Its actually a 2-D array!

Comment: The for loop should start at 1, since in Excel rows start at 1, and keeping it as is will result in having the values of the cells shifted up by 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
ReDim array1(1 to nrow, 1 to ncol)
```

and then

```
Range("C4").Resize(nrow,ncol).Value = array1
```

This way you make sure the array is 1-base which is what Excel likes, and the output range is exactly the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're doing `for i = 0`  instead of `for i = 1`

when i = 0, you're pointing at row 3; If you did sth like `array1(i) = Range("C" & i)`, not adding 3, you'd probably get an error

**edit**

following brettdj's comment, this isn't an untested answer. It's a head up for an error in the code. To be a full answer, do as I say, starting the loop at 1 and then add, as in the accepted answer

`Range("AY4:AY" & nrow + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(array1)`